# what is the problem running osdlyrics in ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10

i succesfully compiled and installed from https://github.com/osdlyrics/osdlyrics
But there is problem on loading it.

```
android@android:~/osdlyrics$ osdlyrics
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant
*Error*: in function _start_daemon_cb: ol_main.c[758]
Unable to start daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.osdlyrics.Daemon exited with status 1
^X
```

i followed the following from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1724078/comments/4

which led me to

```
android@android:~$ osdlyrics
*Error*: in function _start_daemon_cb: ol_main.c[758]
Unable to start daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.osdlyrics.Daemon exited with status 1
```

post from https://github.com/osdlyrics/osdlyrics/issues/23 and https://github.com/osdlyrics/osdlyrics/issues/21
lead me to

```
android@android:~$ sudo pip2 install pycurl
The directory '/home/android/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/android/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pycurl
  Downloading pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz (182kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 184kB 3.3MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-YErRpJ/pycurl/setup.py", line 823, in <module>
        ext = get_extension(sys.argv, split_extension_source=split_extension_source)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-YErRpJ/pycurl/setup.py", line 497, in get_extension
        ext_config = ExtensionConfiguration(argv)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-YErRpJ/pycurl/setup.py", line 71, in __init__
        self.configure()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-YErRpJ/pycurl/setup.py", line 107, in configure_unix
        raise ConfigurationError(msg)
    __main__.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-YErRpJ/pycurl/
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1724078/comments/4

Comment: Now see if this helps: https://github.com/osdlyrics/osdlyrics/issues/23 which leads to this: https://github.com/osdlyrics/osdlyrics/issues/21

Comment: i had gone through that post .. but again nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on ubuntu 18.04, the solution for me was to install the python dependencies mentioned here

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/osdlyrics-git/

and instead of using pip to install them I just used apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install python-chardet python-dbus python-gobject python-pycurl
```